# Bootstrap FontAwesome not displaying correctly

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a simple ASP.NET webforms application which uses Bootstrap FontAwesome to provide various icons. I recently had to build a new server environment for this application. However, when I deployed the web application to the new server, the FontAwesome icons no longer display correctly (just showing small squares for all icons now).

The new server is running Windows Server 2008, IIS7. I'm viewing the application in IE8 but I've tested in Chrome with the same result.

I've placed

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

at the top of my MasterPage head section,

```
Response.AppendHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=Edge");
```

in the Page_Load event of the MasterPage

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

between the

```
<system.webServer>
```

tags in my Web.config.

This application has been working up until now; no changes have been made to the application itself, it's a direct copy of what has been working on other servers (also running Windows Server 8, IIS7).

Comment: Are you actually loading the font awesome script?

Comment: Bootstrap and FontAwesome files are stored locally. No changes have been made to the application when copying from previous server running same WS version and IIS..

Comment: I have no idea why this couldn't be working then, other than the FA script simply not being included.